# Let $z=x+iy$, express the qiven quantity in terms of $ x $ and $y$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I am having trouble with this problem. In problem $14$, let $z=x+iy$. Express the given quantity in terms of $x$ and $y$.
$14$. $|z+5\bar{z}|$

Comment: Try plugging $z = x + iy$ into your equation and then evaluate. Recall that $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and $\bar{z} = x - iy$.

Answer (score 1):

We have: $$|z + 5\bar{z}| = |x+iy + 5(x - iy)| = |6x - 4iy| = \sqrt{36x^2+16y^2} = 2\sqrt{9x^2+4y^2}$$